# How to fix wordpress site url attaching to social media links in the widget?

Tags: widgets

I'm using the Willow theme and when I "customize" the social media widget in the footer for some reason it attaches the site's url to the buttons.

For example, I have inputted the Facebook link for the Facebook button but when I go to click it, it shows up as:

`myWordPressSite.com/www.facebook.com/` instead of just `www.facebook.com/`

I'm not sure what is causing it, I'm not well versed in WP, but I want to learn how to fix something like that. Do I need to access the jQuery UI Widget? I have full admin access incase anyone is wondering.

I'm not sure what other kind of details you may need but please let me know and I will provide what I can

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left `http://` or `https://` off the links. For example:

```
www.facebook.com/
```

will be treated as a relative link to the current URL, while:

```
https://www.facebook.com
```

is the actual URL to Facebook. You need to enter the whole thing so the browser knows that it's a link to another domain/website. This applies wherever you enter links. It's not a WordPress or theme issue, it's just not writing URLs correctly.

Comment: Oh man I'm such a moron, I don't know why I thought the widget was doing that part already but it makes sense that it wouldn't be able tell whether I'm entering a secure address or not. I was looking at it as if I wasn't putting it into an href but a regular address bar like in chrome. Thanks Jacob!